# How to change the class of a div with only css

Tags: html, css

I know there are ways to do this that have already been stated, but none of them seem to be applicable to my situation. Essentially I am trying to edit a website's CSS that I don't own. I just think it looks bad and functions poorly and since I have to use it every day, I want it to at least look good on my own browser. I am doing this with the Firefox Stylus extension to add CSS, but I can't change the already made CSS or HTML. I can essentially add and prioritize my own stylesheet. Just as an example, the website, which I will refer to as *f.com*, has a checkbox on the sign-in page (to remember your username). I have some code to make the checkbox look nicer, but said code applies to the checkbox class.

```
//removed all the unnecessary checkbox code
.checkbox {
    /*stuff*/
}
```

*F.com* doesn't use such a class and its checkbox uses the form-group class. I cant apply my code to this class because it is used in other places and I would affect things that weren't checkboxes. I want to, through CSS, because I can't to my knowledge use javascript, change the div containing the checkbox's class. (I want to set it equal to the checkbox class.) This is just one example, so while alternatives to this specific checkbox case are appreciated, they don't pertain to my main question.

EDIT: As an example, this is how I've seen it done in javascript.

```
document.getElementById('div id').className = "checkbox";
```

EDIT: As requested, here is the HTML for the checkbox currently.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="" data-val="true" data-val-required="The RememberUsername field is required." id="RememberUsername" name="RememberUsername" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="RememberUsername" type="hidden" value="false">
    <label for="RememberUsername">Remember My Username</label>
</div>
```

If I inspect the page and change the div's class to "checkbox", the Stylus plugin will detect that and change the colors for example. I want to change the class via CSS so that it can look like that anytime I go on *F.com*. Again, this is **just an example** and I would prefer a general solution.

Comment: CSS: Cascading Style Sheets. It's whole purpose is to style. I don't think you can change attributes or classNames or so (but it can edit content of pseudo-elements).

Comment: So you think it's just impossible?

Comment: Please post the HTML of this checkbox you want to edit.

Comment: @AndrewL64 like I said, this is only an example and the checkbox is not the main focus of the question. I will upload the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS does not allow for functional programming as its solely for styling markup like HTML. This process can easily be done in Javascript just as you have shown in your edit.

With the inability up change the HTML to add a new selector such as an id or class to an attribute, you won't be able to select said HTML elements from a stylesheet without the proper access to the websites files.

Comment: Then do you think I could run javascript within CSS? I am quite new to all this as I am not a web developer, I just want a better experience on a crappy website.  Also, if you think it's possible, I can upload a new question asking about that instead. I just thought that if it wasn't possible we could just clarify it here and now.

Comment: Unfortunately no, CSS is strictly styling and is not a functional programming language. It is only for styling content. To alter the HTML itself, I recommend you use the console. in chrome you press f12 and you can use the console to select html elements and add styling that way. See this page for selector examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style

Comment: I'm assuming I would have to do that every time I opened the webpage for every change I make though. I don't think that's viable, but thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it would reset every time the page is requested from the web server. All styles reset each time a hot puts a new request in place. Glad I could help!